# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Intellij Plugin

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm trying to build a plugin for Intellij but I'm getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` at runtime every time my code point to a class in another module or to an external library.

Everything works fine in my tests and in the sandbox via `runIde`.

I also managed to reproduce the error by creating a new project with just an action and a module with a class and an empty method.

root gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.31'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.3.12'
}

group 'test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    compile project(':testmodule')
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
intellij {
    version '2018.1.6'
}
patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes """
      Add change notes here.

      most HTML tags may be used"""
}
```

action:

```
package action

import com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.*
import packages.OtherModuleClass

class TestAction : AnAction() {
    override fun actionPerformed(e: AnActionEvent?) {
        OtherModuleClass().otherModuleMethod()
    }
}
```

other module class:

```
package packages

class OtherModuleClass {

    fun otherModuleMethod() {}

}
```

Comment: > java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

on what class?

is this class public?

Comment: @AlexanderZolotov yes is public, my code compiles, my unit tests run, launching the plugin in sandbox works. The problem is when I take the generated .jar file and I install it on the IDE for doing a real test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out what my problem was.

I was installing in my IDE the `jar` in `build/libs` instead of the `zip` in `build/distributions`.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is looking for a solution for similar problem, I fixed it by adding the java plugin in build.gradle

```
apply plugin "java"
```